# How can I fix 'Non-existent config key: MODEL.DENSEPOSE_ON' error in Flask using detectron2-densepose?

Tags: detectron

I have made multiple attempts to reinstall it, but whenever I press the button to use DensePose on the uploaded image, I encounter the following error: "KeyError: 'Non-existent config key: MODEL.DENSEPOSE_ON'". You can view the error message (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxiAn.png).

I have successfully imported detectron2-densepose into my website using Conda environment. The purpose of utilizing DensePose is to detect human bodies based on the uploaded image.